# Setting Up User alerts

Tags: alert

I have created a list on SharePoint and this list has an alert attached to it so it emails a particular user when it is added to. I want to set it so when a user adds to the list it also sends them an alert, it may not be the same user each time.

Any idea if this can be done and how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using SharePoint Designer, you can create a workflow that will send an email notification to the "Created By" person on the list.  
You can use Designer to set-up a single workflow that will do all you describe (e.g. email notify a particular user and created by person).